# htaccess in files folder breaks displaying of images

Tags: 7, files, media, .htaccess

I installed media module and all files in /file directory became unreachable - browser gives 500 internal server error. I can confirm files exist there. After removing htaccess from files directory, everything works ok. Could be that toot htaccess is not properly configured? (images located in root directory display ok)

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# cele domeny (aliasy)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]

# subdomeny (s nebo bez www na zacatku)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

# aliasy - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

# subdomeny - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

#fix for infinite loops - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
#Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
<Files favicon.ico>
  # There is no end quote below, for compatibility with Apache 1.3.
  ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.
</Files>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "recently I installed media module and all files in /file directory became unreachable". That can't be correct. The media module doesn't contain any .htaccess files. I assuming you are trying to say that you recently started to use Media and discovered that the images in the files folder doesn't display? If so, update your question text - and remove the media tag.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Drupal specific question. However, enough Drupal users have this Apache problem that it makes sense to answer.

1. Whenever you get a `500 internal server error` you should check the webserver error log. (Any decent hoster gives you access to that file.) The error log normal contain a rather clear message about what is wrongly configured.
2. If removing the .htaccess file fixes the problem, you know that one of [Apache directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/quickreference.html) in the file causes the error. Finding the directive if you don't have access to the error log can be a lot of work. However, reading the [AllowOverride directive documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) will help by pointing to the most likely problem directives - unless it's just wrong syntax ... Often the problem is the "Options" directive as tenken already replied.

Answer (score 0):

no i had the same issue the other day. It's more likely the `.htaccess` file in your `files` directory has directives not allowed by your webhost or just improper directives.

My files .htaccess in it was an upgrade from Drupal6 -> Drupal7 and had:
`Options None` in it and this broke my logo file, and 2 CSS files -- but everything else was ok.

Htaccess files `nest` so it's most likely the nearest `.htaccess` file to the affected files is causing the problems.

**EDIT**

This line is missing closing quotations in your root .htaccess file:

> ErrorDocument 404 "The requested file favicon.ico was not found.

But thats likely not the issue, i guess it could be.

Other than that assure these are the only .htaccess files on your site and examine them thoroughly.

Comment: Hi, my htaccess in files folder looks like default one. I updated it in my question. The problem is that files show only if I comment EVERYTHING including the security directives.

Comment: I doubt that you tested each line separately ;-) It's typically just one line, for example "Options None" which is a well-known and *old* problem - see for example https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/68077